# Viewcomponent alternative for ajax refresh

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a viewcomponent that contains some reusable business logic that embed in various pages.  This has been working fine.  However, I now have a requirement to refresh the viewcomponent using ajax.

Is there any way to accomplish this?  From what I have read, it is not possible, although that info was a bit outdated.
If it is not possible, what is the best alternative?

Comment: Just as a thought.. ajax need a url to get fresh content. Which means adding an action in the controller.  That action could have a view which invokes the ViewComponent.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On beta7 it is now possible to return a ViewComponent directly from a controller. Check the MVC/Razor section of [the announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta7.aspx)

> The new ViewComponentResult in MVC makes it easy to return the result
>   of a ViewComponent from an action. This allows you to easily expose
>   the logic of a ViewComponent as a standalone endpoint.

So you could have a simple view component like this:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "MyViewComponent")]
public class MyViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
        return Content($"The current time is {time}");
    }
}
```

Create a method in a controller like:

```
public IActionResult MyViewComponent()
{
    return ViewComponent("MyViewComponent");
}
```

And do a better job than my quick and dirty ajax refresh:

```
var container = $("#myComponentContainer");
var refreshComponent = function () {
    $.get("/Home/MyViewComponent", function (data) { container.html(data); });
};

$(function () { window.setInterval(refreshComponent, 1000); });
```

Of course, prior to beta7 you could create a view as the workaround suggested by @eedam or use the approach described in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009326/how-to-invoke-a-view-component-from-controller)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Due to a bit of a time crunch, I just went the route of returning a partialView from my controller which solved my issue.  I may go back and refactor to this solution when we move to beta 7.

Comment: Hi ! Can you post a detailed example of your javascript ? Can't we use old @Ajax helper ?

Comment: As far as I know, the ajax helpers are still part of [their backlog](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2015). Regarding the JS, the 3rd code snippet is the most simple JS you would need to refresh the part of the html containing the view component

Comment: would have been perfect except that,its rendering the layout. How do i make it render without layout/

Comment: I have just tried the solution above in RC1 and didn't return the layout. Are you using RC1 or RC2? Have you tried the exact code above or do you have additional extra code?

Comment: Why not returning Json objects when incoming request is AJAX? This way you don't need to transfer the view for each individual request. @DanielJ.G.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and probably is what I would do most of the times. But its a separated discussion from the original question.

Comment: Not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if the latest .NET core doesn't allow it... but when I try to return ViewComponent, I get "non-invocable member viewcomponent cannot be used like a method"  I see someone else with the same problem https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7051

Comment: Worked fine for me on VS2019 Core 3.1. Thanks