# MVC6 EF7 Viewcomponent ajax refresh issues

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In reference to [Viewcomponent alternative for ajax refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618759/viewcomponent-alternative-for-ajax-refresh).  I can't get the ajax to refresh in MVC6. The JavaScript container finds the Div value but the data is not updating. Any ideas would be appreciated!

ViewComponent - Default.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<My.Models.Queue>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @item.Queue
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="Queue" class="blink">@Component.Invoke("Queue")</div>
```

javascript:

```
var container = document.getElementById("Queue");
var refreshComponent = function () {
$.get("Shared/Components/Queue", function (data) { container[data]; });};
$(function () { window.setInterval(refreshComponent, 1000); });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't make Ajax request directly to the **ViewComponent**, but you can invoke it from any **Controller**'s method like it's described in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618759/viewcomponent-alternative-for-ajax-refresh) that you mentioned in your question.

So you should create a simple **Controller**'s method like:

```
public IActionResult QueueViewComponent()
{
    return ViewComponent("QueueViewComponent");
}
```

And call it from your JavaScript:

```
var container = $("#queueComponentContainer");
var refreshComponent = function () {
    $.get("/Home/QueueViewComponent", function (data) { container.html(data); });
};

$(function () { window.setInterval(refreshComponent, 1000); });
```

Where the **Home** is a **Controller**'s name of your newly created method.

Comment: Thank you Sami Kuhmonen.  I will try this.   I have been getting by with just refreshing the entire window with JavaScript rather than just the data component.