# Razor Pages - Is it possible to route to a View Component for AJAX refresh

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

**Context:**

I have a section of a view that I want to update on a regular interval via JS.

**What I have done so far:**

Using the information given in: [Viewcomponent alternative for ajax refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618759/viewcomponent-alternative-for-ajax-refresh)

- created a view component that encapsulates the region that I want to refresh
- attempted to create a custom route to a view component as follows

```js
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Components/ViewComponent/default", "FriendlyRouteAlias");
```

- use the following script to attempt to load the (updated) view component and inject the value into a div:

```js
<script>
    var container = $(".DataToUpdate");
    var refreshComponent = function () {
        $.get("Route/to/view/component", function (data) { container.html(data); });
    };

    $(function () { window.setInterval(refreshComponent, 1000); });
</script>
```

Is it even possible to load a View Component this way or should I be looking at another way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Have you tried putting your view component in a view and returning that from an action in a controller?  Then once you have the view you can set it as the contents of a tag like a div for example.

Comment: Create a WebAPI controller and call that via AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters suggested, I was able to get it working by using an MVC controller action to return the view component directly. I will add that I used an MVC controller rather than an API controller because I was dealing with a view rather than data. (see [Difference between ApiController and Controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494966/difference-between-apicontroller-and-controller-in-asp-net-mvc))