# Can I invoke methods on a view component from javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I made a component:

```
public class CatSearchComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

@await Component.InvokeAsync("CatSearchComponent")
```

Within the component I have a button that I want to use jquery $.ajax to call a method and render some data within the component, e.g. an action called `GetCats()` that returns some Json data.

It would be nice to put this method into the component since it's component specific.

However I am not sure what the url would be to put into my $.ajax call to call such a method, or even if it's allowed in MVC.

I could create a new controller and put an action on it to get the data but it would be nice if it was coupled with my ViewComponent. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think it is doable. I don't see any workaround except using controllers in mvc pattern.

Comment: No. Think of a view component as simply a way to wrap some complex logic around a partial. It's not a thing that continues to exist or that is reactive to requests like a controller; it's instantiated during the view rendering and then dumped afterwards.

Comment: I really can't see the point of view components at all, you may as well simply create a controller I think. Unless there's some advantage I am missing, it's like a controller that forces you to have only 1 method

Answer (score 0):

You can, as it happens, but not directly.

You can create an ActionResult in an MVC Controller, which returns the ViewComponent result; then, in JavaScript/jQuery, call the Controller.

See this StackOverflow answer for a full description and code:

[Viewcomponent alternative for ajax refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618759/viewcomponent-alternative-for-ajax-refresh)

(Full credit to @daniel-j-g)